# Using Power BI with SAAS Application

Tags: azure, powerbi, saas

I want to use Power BI with my SAAS application . so My question is which option will be better for me Power BI embed or Power BI Premium.

Comment: Did you read the difference between the two? Did you try anything? You would only use embedded if you are the SaaS builder and you are deploying it to people

Comment: Are you licensed for Power BI Premium?

Answer (score 0):

You can use powerbi embed for SAAS application with a professional powerbi account. Powerbi along with azure offers api to access reports and dashboards which you can integrate in your application. Follow this link for a start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XSAHwE21Buk